# Which RPC Library is best and Official for Openerp?

Tags: odoo, rpc

I found some RPC Library (Python) for driving Odoo/OpenERP.

```
openerplib
oerplib
erppeek
xmlrpclib
odoorpc
```

Please let me know, which one is Best/Good/Official?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm using xmlrpclib. if you want an example of it than you may look at this http://odedrabhavesh.blogspot.in/2014/12/xml-rpc-web-services-in-openerp.html

Answer (score 1):

`openerplib` is a PHP library, probably not what you want if you're planning to use Pyhton.

`xmlrpclib` is Python standard library for XML-RPC. You can perfectly work with it, but it won't be the most pleasant library to work with. See the [official docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/api_integration.html) for more details on it.

The other libraries are wrappers around `xmlrpclib`.

`oerplib` and `odoorpc` are from the same author, and I believe that the former is an older version (pre Odoo rebranding), so you should  prefer the later. It is up to date, so it can be an option.

`erppeek` is up to date and is the project with more more activity and contributors. It also provides an API wrapper, but is build to be a console client for Odoo servers. AFAIK is widely used for that.

My advice it to have a look at the doc of `odoorpc` and `erppeek` and pick that one you feel better suited for your needs.

Comment: Can you please add some more information as to why this is the best library to use, besides the fact that you say it's the best?

Comment: Fair enough. I'll try expanding with that.